# Change subsection font in TOC, but keep dotting and page number unaffected

Tags: table-of-contents, pdftex, titletoc

I am trying to to change the subsection font to italics in the TOC, and have managed to do so like in this MWE typesetted with `pdflatexmk` with the TeXShop app for MacOS:

```
%% Define document class with options
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,openright]{report} 

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Output font encoding. Standard option.
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Input font encoding. Standard option.
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{geometry} % Easy modification of the page layout.
\geometry{a4paper,inner=28mm,outer=25mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm} % Required layout
\pagestyle{headings} % Standard pagestyle with headers (section/chapter names) and footer (page number)

% Modify chapter headings:
\usepackage{titlesec}
\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
        %\huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \Huge\bfseries \thechapter.\space%
        %\par\nobreak
        %\vskip 20\p@           
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\makeatother

% Make subsection headings boldformat and in italics in text.
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{14}{12}\bfseries\itshape}{\thesection}{1em}{}
  
 % For subsection TOC headings
\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents{subsection} % set formatting for \section -
[6em]                 % adjust left margin
{\itshape}             % font formatting
{\contentslabel{2.3em}} % section label and offset
{\hspace*{-2.3em}}
{\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor} % Allows text and background colors to be controlled
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{ % hyperref package options
     pdffitwindow=false,            % controls whether window is resized to fit pdf-page when pdf-viewer is opened
     pdfstartview={FitV},           % fits the pdf-page to the window when pdf-viwer is opened
     pdftitle={My title},           % title for pdf-file properties
     pdfauthor={MSc Candidate}, % author for pdf-file properties
     pdfsubject={MSc Thesis},   % subject of the document for pdf-file properties
     pdfkeywords={keyword1} {keyword2} {keyword3} {keyword4}, % list of keywords for pdf-file properties
         pdfnewwindow=true,             % links open in new window
         linktoc=page,                          % only page numbers in toc act as links (instead of the whole entry)
     colorlinks=true,               % false: links are shown as boxes around text; true: links are shown as colored text
     linkcolor=BrickRed,        % color of internal links (change box color with linkbordercolor). Default: red
}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{2} % Control the depth of the table of contents entries (1=section, 2=subsection, 3=subsubsection)
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}
\cleardoublepage % Start new page for the \addcontentsline{toc} command
\phantomsection % Needed for hyperref to correctly link to the table of contents
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Table of Contents} % Add the table of contents to the table of contents at the section level
\tableofcontents % Produce the table of contents
\thispagestyle{plain} % Remove headers from second page of table of contents

\chapter{Chapter heading}

\section{Section heading}
\lipsum[1]

\subsection{Subsection heading in italics}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE_TOC]

However, as seen in the picture, both the page numbering and the dotting are italicised as well. Additionally, the spacing between the dots are larger. I am trying to keep the dotting and page number in the standard format, i.e. not italicised and with standard spacing between the dots, but I can't figure out how, and I have not found any other posts on this exact question. Therefore, I was hoping for some assistance here.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `tocloft` package instead of `titletoc` for the subsection ToC entries.

```
% tocsubsecprob.tex  SE 601868

%% Define document class with options
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,openright]{report} 

\usepackage{comment}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Output font encoding. Standard option.
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Input font encoding. Standard option.
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{geometry} % Easy modification of the page layout.
\geometry{a4paper,inner=28mm,outer=25mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm} % Required layout
\pagestyle{headings} % Standard pagestyle with headers (section/chapter names) and footer (page number)

% Modify chapter headings:
\usepackage{titlesec}
\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
        %\huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \Huge\bfseries \thechapter.\space%
        %\par\nobreak
        %\vskip 20\p@           
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\makeatother

% Make subsection headings boldformat and in italics in text.
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{14}{12}\bfseries\itshape}{\thesection}{1em}{}
  
 % For subsection TOC headings
\begin{comment}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents{subsection} % set formatting for \section -
[6em]                 % adjust left margin
{\itshape}             % font formatting
{\contentslabel{2.3em}} % section label and offset
{\hspace*{-2.3em}}
{\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}
\end{comment}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecfont}{\itshape}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor} % Allows text and background colors to be controlled
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{ % hyperref package options
     pdffitwindow=false,            % controls whether window is resized to fit pdf-page when pdf-viewer is opened
     pdfstartview={FitV},           % fits the pdf-page to the window when pdf-viwer is opened
     pdftitle={My title},           % title for pdf-file properties
     pdfauthor={MSc Candidate}, % author for pdf-file properties
     pdfsubject={MSc Thesis},   % subject of the document for pdf-file properties
     pdfkeywords={keyword1} {keyword2} {keyword3} {keyword4}, % list of keywords for pdf-file properties
         pdfnewwindow=true,             % links open in new window
         linktoc=page,                          % only page numbers in toc act as links (instead of the whole entry)
     colorlinks=true,               % false: links are shown as boxes around text; true: links are shown as colored text
     linkcolor=BrickRed,        % color of internal links (change box color with linkbordercolor). Default: red
}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{2} % Control the depth of the table of contents entries (1=section, 2=subsection, 3=subsubsection)
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}
\cleardoublepage % Start new page for the \addcontentsline{toc} command
\phantomsection % Needed for hyperref to correctly link to the table of contents
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Table of Contents} % Add the table of contents to the table of contents at the section level
\tableofcontents % Produce the table of contents
\thispagestyle{plain} % Remove headers from second page of table of contents

\chapter{Chapter heading}

\section{Section heading}
\lipsum[1]

\subsection{Subsection heading in italics}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Cheers mate, this was exactly what I was after!

Answer (score 1):

To keep the dotting and page number in the standard format, you can add a `\normalfont` before it. For the dot spacing issue, I didn't figure out how to make it behave exactly like LaTeX default, but I added a separate `\titlecontents` for section to match the dots of the subsection.

```
\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents{section}
[3.8em]
{}
{\contentslabel{2.3em}}
{\hspace*{-2.3em}}
{\normalfont\titlerule*[.8pc]{.}\contentspage}
\titlecontents{subsection} % set formatting for \section -
[6em]                 % adjust left margin
{\itshape}             % font formatting
{\contentslabel{2.3em}} % section label and offset
{\hspace*{-2.3em}}
{\normalfont\titlerule*[.8pc]{.}\contentspage}
```

[image]

Below is the complete code.

```
%% Define document class with options
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,openright]{report} 

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Output font encoding. Standard option.
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Input font encoding. Standard option.
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{geometry} % Easy modification of the page layout.
\geometry{a4paper,inner=28mm,outer=25mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm} % Required layout
\pagestyle{headings} % Standard pagestyle with headers (section/chapter names) and footer (page number)

% Modify chapter headings:
\usepackage{titlesec}
\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
        %\huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \Huge\bfseries \thechapter.\space%
        %\par\nobreak
        %\vskip 20\p@           
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\makeatother

% Make subsection headings boldformat and in italics in text.
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{14}{12}\bfseries\itshape}{\thesection}{1em}{}
  
 % For subsection TOC headings
\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents{section}
[3.8em]
{}
{\contentslabel{2.3em}}
{\hspace*{-2.3em}}
{\normalfont\titlerule*[.8pc]{.}\contentspage}
\titlecontents{subsection} % set formatting for \section -
[6em]                 % adjust left margin
{\itshape}             % font formatting
{\contentslabel{2.3em}} % section label and offset
{\hspace*{-2.3em}}
{\normalfont\titlerule*[.8pc]{.}\contentspage}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor} % Allows text and background colors to be controlled
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{ % hyperref package options
     pdffitwindow=false,            % controls whether window is resized to fit pdf-page when pdf-viewer is opened
     pdfstartview={FitV},           % fits the pdf-page to the window when pdf-viwer is opened
     pdftitle={My title},           % title for pdf-file properties
     pdfauthor={MSc Candidate}, % author for pdf-file properties
     pdfsubject={MSc Thesis},   % subject of the document for pdf-file properties
     pdfkeywords={keyword1} {keyword2} {keyword3} {keyword4}, % list of keywords for pdf-file properties
         pdfnewwindow=true,             % links open in new window
         linktoc=page,                          % only page numbers in toc act as links (instead of the whole entry)
     colorlinks=true,               % false: links are shown as boxes around text; true: links are shown as colored text
     linkcolor=BrickRed,        % color of internal links (change box color with linkbordercolor). Default: red
}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{2} % Control the depth of the table of contents entries (1=section, 2=subsection, 3=subsubsection)
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}
\cleardoublepage % Start new page for the \addcontentsline{toc} command
\phantomsection % Needed for hyperref to correctly link to the table of contents
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Table of Contents} % Add the table of contents to the table of contents at the section level
\tableofcontents % Produce the table of contents
\thispagestyle{plain} % Remove headers from second page of table of contents

\chapter{Chapter heading}

\section{Section heading}
\lipsum[1]

\subsection{Subsection heading in italics}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! It seems to work as requested, but I went with the reply below. Thanks anyway for the help, it's really appreciated!